# String to int - cocoa, objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, numbers

I'm trying to get a value from a NSTextField (Label) and convert it to a int...

```
 minFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
  [minFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterNoStyle];
  NSNumber *minTimeValue = [minFormatter numberFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.minTextLabel stringValue]]];
  [minFormatter release];
  int minTimeValueInt;
  minTimeValueInt = [minTimeValue intValue];
  NSLog(@"%@", minTimeValueInt);
```

I can't find anything wrong with it, but the NSLog returns (null) when I log the `minTimeValueInt` what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%@` is the format string for an object. It's interpreting `minTimeValueInt` as a pointer, which is apparently 0 (null). Use `%d` instead.

Comment: "00" still parses to the integer 0, which is equivalent (in this architecture) to null.